# Solve $(1-x^2)y''-xy'-y=e^{\arcsin x}$.

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

### Problem

Solve $$(1-x^2)y''-xy'-y=e^{\arcsin x}.$$

Can it be solved to get the general solution?

Comment: You have rep of over 4000. I have to assume there is a language difficulty here, because this is a very poorly worded question.

Comment: Did you solve at least $(1-x^2)y''-xy'-y=0$ ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $t=\sin^{-1}x$ ,

Then $x=\sin t$

$\dfrac{dy}{dx}=\dfrac{\dfrac{dy}{dt}}{\dfrac{dx}{dt}}=(\sec t)\dfrac{dy}{dt}$

$\dfrac{d^2y}{dx^2}=\dfrac{d}{dx}\left((\sec t)\dfrac{dy}{dt}\right)=\dfrac{\dfrac{d}{dt}\left((\sec t)\dfrac{dy}{dt}\right)}{\dfrac{dx}{dt}}=\dfrac{(\sec t)\dfrac{d^2y}{dt^2}+(\sec t\tan t)\dfrac{dy}{dt}}{\cos t}=(\sec^2t)\dfrac{d^2y}{dt^2}+(\sec^2t\tan t)\dfrac{dy}{dt}$

$\therefore\dfrac{d^2y}{dt^2}+(\tan t)\dfrac{dy}{dt}-(\tan t)\dfrac{dy}{dt}-y=e^t$

$\dfrac{d^2y}{dt^2}-y=e^t$

$y=C_1e^t+C_2e^{-t}+\dfrac{te^t}{2}$

$y=C_1e^{\sin^{-1}x}+C_2e^{-\sin^{-1}x}+\dfrac{e^{\sin^{-1}x}\sin^{-1}x}{2}$